# How do I send the user to a SAML login page using OpenSAML?

Tags: java, authentication, saml, opensaml

I have an app that already has a login system and user objects, etc. I want to adapt it so it can authenticate using a SAML identity provider.

To do so I need to construct a page that sends the user to the identity provider to login. Here is what I've come up with so far to test with:

```
public String getSamlLoginPage() throws IOException, ConfigurationException {
    DefaultBootstrap.bootstrap();

    AuthnRequest authnRequest = buildSamlObject(AuthnRequest.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME,AuthnRequestBuilder.class);

    String myResponseUrl = "http://localhost:8080/samltest/saml?action=samlLogin";
    String serviceProviderEntityId = "someProviderEntityId";


    // set information in request
    {
        authnRequest.setForceAuthn(false);
        authnRequest.setIsPassive(false);
        authnRequest.setIssueInstant(new DateTime());
        authnRequest.setDestination(myResponseUrl);
        authnRequest.setProtocolBinding(SAMLConstants.SAML2_ARTIFACT_BINDING_URI);
        authnRequest.setAssertionConsumerServiceURL(myResponseUrl);
        authnRequest.setID(""+UUID.randomUUID().getLeastSignificantBits());

        Issuer issuer = buildSamlObject(Issuer.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME, IssuerBuilder.class);
        issuer.setValue(serviceProviderEntityId);
        authnRequest.setIssuer(issuer);

        NameIDPolicy nameIDPolicy = buildSamlObject(NameIDPolicy.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME, NameIDPolicyBuilder.class);
        nameIDPolicy.setSPNameQualifier(serviceProviderEntityId);
        nameIDPolicy.setAllowCreate(true);
        nameIDPolicy.setFormat("urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient");
        authnRequest.setNameIDPolicy(nameIDPolicy);

        RequestedAuthnContext requestedAuthnContext = buildSamlObject(RequestedAuthnContext.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME,RequestedAuthnContextBuilder.class);
        requestedAuthnContext.setComparison(AuthnContextComparisonTypeEnumeration.MINIMUM);

        AuthnContextClassRef authnContextClassRef = buildSamlObject(AuthnContextClassRef.DEFAULT_ELEMENT_NAME,AuthnContextClassRefBuilder.class);
        authnContextClassRef.setAuthnContextClassRef("urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:ac:classes:PasswordProtectedTransport");

        requestedAuthnContext.getAuthnContextClassRefs().add(authnContextClassRef);
        authnRequest.setRequestedAuthnContext(requestedAuthnContext);
    }



    String samlRequestStr = XMLUtil.doc2String( authnRequest.getDOM() );
    byte[] samlRequest = samlRequestStr.getBytes();  // <samlp:AuthnRequest>

    ByteArrayOutputStream bout = new ByteArrayOutputStream(500);
    Base64.encode(samlRequest,bout);

    return
        "<html><body>"
        +"<form method=\"post\" action=\"https://idp.example.org/SAML2/SSO/POST\">"
            +"  <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"SAMLRequest\" value=\""+ bout.toString() +"\" />"
//                +"  <input type=\"hidden\" name=\"RelayState\" value=\"someToken\" />"
            +"  <input type=\"submit\" value=\"Submit\" />"
            +" </form>"
        +"<body></html>";
}

private <SAMLObjectType extends SAMLObject, BuilderT extends SAMLObjectBuilder<SAMLObjectType>> SAMLObjectType buildSamlObject(javax.xml.namespace.QName defaultElementName, Class<BuilderT> type) {
    XMLObjectBuilderFactory builderFactory = org.opensaml.Configuration.getBuilderFactory();
    BuilderT requestBuilder = (BuilderT)builderFactory.getBuilder(defaultElementName);
    return requestBuilder.buildObject();
}
```

I'll need to change the action to point to the actual identity provider. Beyond that, what am I supposed to put into the Request object? All I need is for the identity provider to verify that the user is a real user (they'll login with email and password at the identity provider) and then communicate to me what their email address is along with some sort of signature that I can validate to prove that the user has been validated by the identity provider.

All other information about the user is stored locally, so email and idp signature is all I need.

Comment: after you send the user to the login page, how do you let him enter his credentials and fetch the saml response from the idp?

Answer (score 0):

The saml request has to contain a couple of things. It usually also have to be signed. [Here](https://blog.samlsecurity.com/search?s=authnrequest) is a blog post I have written on how to create a Authn SAML request using OpenSAML

I also have a book, [A Guide to OpenSAML](https://blog.samlsecurity.com/a-guide-to-opensamlv3.html), that gives a good introduction to SAML and the OpenSAML library.

Comment: I really don't know what the fields do, but I've filled in the same fields you did and updated the code in my question. The value of myResponseUrl is just the url that the response would be posted to. I don't know what value serviceProviderEntityId should have. I don't see anything in there to tell the idp that an email address should be returned to me in the response. Is what I did valid? What else do I need to put in?

Comment: Usually the IDP decides what to return. ServiceProviderEntityId is the id of the identity provider. The whole identity federation usually starts by exchanging metadata, an xml with info about each endpoint. ServiceProviderEntityId should be in there

Comment: I get the feeling you know very little about SAML, I would suggest you begin reading this https://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/27819/sstc-saml-tech-overview-2.0-cd-02.pdf